Create extended class via Reflection
I have a nice and clean interface like so:
public interface Mapping<I extends Input, O extends Output> {
    O calculate(I input);

    Class<I> getInputClass();

    Class<O> getOutputClass();
}

Let's assume for simplicity that Input and Output are empty interfaces.
I want to define Mappings at runtime and instantiate them via reflection. One example for such a Mapping is the following:
public class DoublerMapping implements Mapping<DoublerInput, DoublerOutput> {
    @Override
    DoublerOutput calculate(DoublerInput input){
       DoublerOutput output = new DoublerOutput();
       output.setValue(input.getValue() * 2);
       return output;
    }

    @Override
    Class<DoublerInput> getInputClass(){
       return DoublerInput.class;
    }

    @Override
    Class<O> getOutputClass(){
       return DoublerInput.class;
    }
}

When instantiating Mappings by reflection, however, I can only use getInputClass() and getOutputClass() to instantiate Inputs and Outputs respectively (utilizing mapping.getInputClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()), instead of their actual extension. I don't want the Mapping to take a generic Input as I want to make sure it's getting the proper class I it's expecting. I also can't pull the getValue() and setValue() methods to the interface, as they could take any arguments and have different signatures.
How do I go to create an I extends Input at runtime and feeding it back to the parameterized Mapping class? Not even mapping.execute(mapping.getInputClass().getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()) compiles.
Or is there a better way to achieve this?

what's your current reflection logic?

Generally speaking, you can't. Generics exists only at compile-time. At some point at runtime you must pass the class you want to instantiate and so, I think, the whole approach is pointless.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure

Outside my wheelhouse, but might this help? JEP 466: Class-File API (Second Preview)

I managed to solve my own issue. The primary problem is to feed the I back into the Mapping class. @rzwitserloot's answer is a good improvement to the avoid verbose and bad code, but still doesn't get the code to compile when calling the calculate method with an Input generated from the Mapping itself.
I could fin the solution here: https://angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ207
The Mapping interface still needs a method to get the actual I extends Input at runtime like so:
public interface Mapping<I extends Input, O extends Output> {
  O calculate(I input);

  Supplier<I> newInput(); // thanks rzwitserloot!

  Class<I> getInputClass(); // needed to make things work
}

The caller of the generic calculate method has to do the following:
   Output calculateInMapping(Mapping<? extends Input, ? extends Output> mapping) {
      Input input = mapping.newInput().get();

      // maybe do some stuff with the input

      return calculate(mapping, input);
   }
   
   private static <T extends Input> Output calculate(Mapping<T, ? extends Output> mapping, Input input) {
       return mapping.calculate(mapping.getInputType().cast(input));
   } 

And for completeness, here's how the DoublingMapping would look like:
public class DoublerMapping implements Mapping<DoublerInput, DoublerOutput> {
  @Override
  DoublerOutput calculate(DoublerInput input){
   DoublerOutput output = new DoublerOutput();
   output.setValue(input.getValue() * 2);
   return output;
  }

  @Override
  Supplier<DoublerInput> newInput(){
   return DoublerInput::new;
  }

  @Override
  Class<DoublerInput> getInputClass(){
   return DoublerInput.class;
  }
}

P.S.: If you're willing to tolerate an "unchecked" cast warning, you can also get away without the getInputClass() method above and just cast:
private static <T extends Input> Output execute(Mapping<T, ? extends Output> mapping, Input input) {
    return mapping.execute((T) input);
}


You don't need that getInputClass. private static <T extends Input> Output execute(Plugin<T, ? extends Output> mapping, T input) {} addresses the problem.

Well it doesn't compile if I do that. reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Input conforms to capture of ? extends Input inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: capture of ? extends Input lower bounds: Input

You can make that work; you're using too many ? where you shouldn't be. ? is highly limiting. I get that it doesn't work for your code right now; I don't have the full code to try to help.

I was hoping my answer above to be a complete example (you just need to wrap the second code snippet in a class). I just corrected a few misnomers.

public <I extends Input, O extends Output> O calculateInMapping(Mapping<I, O> mapping) { ... } is what the signature shuold have been. Find every ? and reconsider it.

If you want to fancy it up, that could be Mapping<? super I, ? extends O> - if you need to map a string to a number, it's fine if your mapper maps any object to an integer.

As mentioned in the question, Mapping is instantiated via reflection, there's nothing I can do about that. It's part of a large codebase I have limited control over. Hence I'm afraid I won't easily get rid of the ? extends

reflection and generics requires 1 cast to assign the generics, you can't avoid that. Do it during reflection and do it on the right thing, i.e. cast the Mapper properly, don't mess about with endless pain when you use it, fix it when you make it.

I agree with your thought process, but I tried that for a while and couldn't find a way to cast the Mapping to <I, O> which is the whole point of the question, unfortunately.

Just cast it. Mapping<TheRightInputType, TheRightOutputType> yadayada. Somebody knows at compile time. Or, if nobody knows (it's 100% a runtime party, everything loaded in via reflection/serialization), then nobody cares. Trust me, there is a way to do it right, you haven't provided enough info, and your own answer is not the right way to go about it.

No one knows, it's one of many things loaded at runtime from a configuration file. I can't cast to I. All I want is to feed it back its I. We can discuss whether the architecture is good or not, but this is a given I have no power over.

P.S.: it is easy to say "there's a right way to do it", and downvote a workaround solution... it's harder to provide an actual solution. All the necessary details are in the question. Let me sum them up for you nicely, simplified to the bare minimum:

I have a Mapping<I extends Input> which has a method foo(I input);
I create the Mapping via reflection (non-negotiable).

How to make sure that foo is callable with the right I and not a generic Input, other than the way described above?

I wrote an entire answer proving that you can do it correctly. The guts to yell at me for 'downvoting the workaround' is impressive in a bad way. You're on your own.

You wrote a good answer regarding the instatiation of the input and how to avoid reflection there; not for the creation of the Mapping itself and most importantly feeding its extended type parameter back to itself. I don't remember yelling, in fact I've been corteous and still am thankful for your time. The link provided to Angelika Langer's website explains why what you claim is doable, is not. If, however, you're not willing to read and understand what I'm commenting, I'm afraid there's no point in discussing further. Good day to you.

Class<I> is your problem.
You want to abstract over the notion of the type itself - you don't want the concept 'some instance of DoublerInput', no, you want to abstract the concept of 'DoublerInput' - the entire class.
It makes sense to think: "Ah, well, DoublerInput.class, which is of type Class<DoublerInput>, will serve as that thing!"
A sensible thought, but, that is wrong.
The answer you are looking for is Factories.
Yes, cliché, but move on from the jokes. It really is what it is for. Class doesn't work for quite a few reasons:

You can't define anything in it. For example, when you write your reflective code, you're just assuming that there's a no-args public constructor. If it doesn't exist, you get no compile time warnings, either in your framework, or in whomever is writing class DoublerInput. There is simply no way to dictate that any 'class that implements Input' must necessarily have a no-args constructor. You also can't define any class-level methods; there's no such thing as an interface for static members, after all.

j.l.Class is incapable of representing type-argsed types. You can't do List<String>.class, and while you can write Class<List<String>> x;, that is meaningless; there is no class reference that uniquely represents specifically the notion of 'lists of strings'. There's just List.class. Not List<String>.class.

Sideshow point perhaps, but, int.class exists, but, generics can't do primitives. In that sense Class<T> is doubly bad; If T contains generics then j.l.Class cannot represent them, and j.l.Class can represent things that generics cannot.


Factories let you fix all of it. You define the notion of a factory and then add whatever you need. For example:
abstract class InputFactory<I extends Input> {
  abstract I create();
}

and now you can make:
final class DoublerInputFactory extends InputFactory<DoublerInput> {
  @Override DoublerInput create() {
    return new DoublerInput();
  }
}

and now all is well: instead of accepting a Class<I>, you accept a InputFactory<I>, and you can invoke .create() on that instance which replaces .getConstructor().newInstance(), which avoids a whole boatload of weird exceptions that are hard to explain in the context of what you're trying to do, and you are guaranteed that the code that powers the object you are provided implements this; if it did not, it wouldn't have compiled in the first place.
You can now also add on whatever you need. Want a concept (such as DoublerInput) to be capable of naming itself? As in, not one particular instance of DoublerInput, but the notion of DoublerInput as a whole?
Just shove a String getName() method in the factory, easy!
Want the concept to be able to, say, clone an instance? Add it to the factory.
Want to convey the concept that any implementing classes must have a constructor that takes, say, an int? Don't do that, instead, stick abstract I create(int arg); into your factory class.
This solves many problems, and 'generics go ape when I attempt to use reflection as a crappy way to re-invent factories' is one of the many problems that this will solve.
When JVM based languages invent the concept of type-level interfaces, they do so by enshrining the factory pattern into the language as a whole. Scala did it; kotlin did it. The amount of boilerplate involved is minimal.
Make factories.
NB: If 'make me an instance of <I>' is all you need your factory to do, you can simply go with java.util.function.Supplier<I>, and providers can write lambdas. Supplier<DoublerInput> doublerInputFactory = DoublerInput::new; works great, and preserves generics. java's own Collection.toArray() uses this same concept to 'fix' its issues with generics, if you want an example / if you want some 'proof' that this is a suitable pattern. "JDK itself has recently employed its use" should help in that regard. You can make your own Factory interface or abstract class if you want the abstraction to be capable of doing more than simply 'just make me an instance'.

Thank you for the thorough answer, it's definitely an improvement on my implementation. However my code still doesn't compile upon calling the calculate method. I created a Supplier<I> newInput() in the mapping. When I callmapping.execute(mapping.newInput().get()) it still won't compile, with the following output: error: incompatible types: Input cannot be converted to CAP#1 Output output = plugin.execute(plugin.newInput().get()); where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: CAP#1 extends Input from capture of ? extends Input

Edit: See my anser below.
